# How to use namespaces when implementing methods?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, header-files

I have a class declaration in a `.hpp` line enclosed in a named namespace:

```
namespace mylib
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public:

        MyClass();
    }
}
```

I plan to implement the class' functionality in a `.cpp` file.

However, both of these methods seem to work:

```
mylib::MyClass::MyClass()
{
}
```

and

```
namespace mylib
{
    MyClass::MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

And so I am left wondering what is the difference between these methods and whether I should prefer one over the other.

Comment: There is no difference at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's personal preference. However you can save code using the `namespace` keyword with brackets. Also these might be easier to read (knowing that everything is in the same namespace anyway).

Also keep in mind that not using `namespace` might get rather tedious and confusing once you start using custom types defined within your class, e.g. a different local class used as a return or parameter type:

```
myNamespace::myClass::myType &myNamespace::myClass::doSomething(const myNamespace::myOtherClass &theOther) {
    // ...
}

namespace myNamespace {
    myClass::myType &myClass::doSomethingDifferent(const myOtherClass &theOther) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mylib::` contains 7 characters

`namespace mylib { }` contains 16 characters (excluding spaces)

Hence, by using the second form you will save typing time as long as you define 3 or more methods.

Comment: Think you got it confused. Once you've got 3 methods using `namespace` is shorter.

Comment: @Mario They were in reverse order in the OP. I've reversed the order in my answer too. It was indeed very confusing!